# Sites icon missing from app launcher

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, applauncher

Users have reported that they are missing the SharePoint "Sites" tile from the Office 365 online app launcher.

I have tried re-syncing users from on-premise Active Directory, re-applying licensing, hiding then re-showing the Sites option under SharePoint admin centre > Settings.

Can someone please help me reset the app launcher tiles for all users?

[image: Offie 365 App Launcher]

Answer (score 1):

The Sites tile has been renamed to SharePoint. Please refer [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-sites-and-portals-in-Office-365-6b85097a-87e0-4611-a29a-dfd49b1a1220) Office team blog about it.

If you want your users to see the Sites Tile, you can always add a custom tile with name Sites by following [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-custom-tiles-to-the-app-launcher-1136115a-75af-4497-b693-640c4ce70bc6) article. I'd suggest not to go this route and recommend sending a communication to users about this change from Microsoft.

Comment: A SharePoint tile isn't available either. I just added a screenshot to the original question.